# When is it justifiable to ignore explanatory variable endogeneity in a regression model?

Tags: instrumental-variables, endogeneity, sensitivity-analysis

I have three related questions:

- Is there a way to conduct a back of the envelop calculation that informs the reader on the degree of endogeneity we should have to bias the OLS estimates in a meaningful way (i.e. either reversing the direction of the estimate or render it nil or providing an estimate that is statistically significantly different from the "unbiased estimate")? More pragmatically, something that informs the reader on the following issue: "the amount of observations for which the value of variable x has to be endogenous, in order to bias the OLS estimate of my independent variable of interest in a statistically significant manner, has to be N"
- I know that a few recent papers have been debating this topic: [Ashley and Parmeter, 2015a](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165176515003870), [Ashley and Parmeter, 2015b](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00181-015-0916-0)--both papers can be found at [Ashley's website](http://ashleymac.econ.vt.edu/), [Kiviet, 2016](https://feb.kuleuven.be/drc/Economics/misc/nesg2016/papers/kiviet.pdf)--available at [Kiviet's website](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165176516302257), and [Ashley and Parmeter, 2018](http://ashleymac.econ.vt.edu/working_papers/Ashley_Parmeter_Credible_OLS_Update_Note.pdf.)--not yet published; the matter does not seem to be settled yet. Do you know alternative literature?
- On the pragmatic side, is there a Stata user's written command to conduct a formal test, instead of a back of the envelop computation?

Comment: Outside of econ, statisticians often call endogeneity "confounding". There is a lot of research on sensitivity analyses for unmeasured confounding by VanderWeele and colleagues. A Google Scholar search for "VanderWeele sensitivity analysis" will yield many results that relate to your question and contain sources.

Comment: This is indeed a very useful tip. I have been skimming this literature recently, mostly related to ad-hoc Stata commands. However, even going through some slides of presentations from VanderWeele, I sense that these methods maybe applied only to cases when the independent variable of interest is a dummy (= 1 if i is treated, = 0 otherwise). @Noah, do you know whether there is something for continuous independent variables of interest? (thus, not strictly about policy evaluation or the like)

Comment: I come from the evaluation side, so I don't know much about continuous independent variables, sorry!